# Asymptotic expansion of hypergeometric 2F2

Tags: asymptotics, hypergeometric-functions

I would like to find an asymptotic expansion for the hypergeometric function

$$
_{2}F_{2}\left(a,b;c,d;z\right),\quad a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

The parameters are fixed. $z$ is real and $z\rightarrow +\infty$.

Could someone shed  light on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$_{2}F_{2}\left(a,b;c,d;z\right)=\frac{\Gamma (c) \Gamma (d)}{\Gamma (a) \Gamma (b)}e^z z^{a+b-c-d}\left(1+{\cal O}(z^{-1})\right)$$

As an example, the plot shows $_{2}F_{2}\left(a,b;c,d;z\right)$ (blue) and the asymptotics (gold) for $a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Could you provide me with some reference book?

Comment: for example https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263796676_A_note_on_the_asymptotic_expansion_of_generalized_hypergeometric_functions